# Why the Resources direrctory is not visible on my project navigatior

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I just started learning [SwiftUI](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) and trying to follow the steps of the [Building lists and navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) example from Apple. Although copied and existing on the project directory, I noticed the `Resources` directory is not visible in my project navigation on Xcode.

The build is successful, but since the app tries to read `landmarkData.json` file from that directory, it throws:

> Could not find landmarkData.json in main bundle.

Why doesn't the `Resources` show up on Xcode? How can I fix this issue?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some things you can verify :

[image: 1]

- Verify if the clock is selected in the search bar. If so, de-select it.
- Try deleting the `Ressources` folder in your projet files. Then, drag and drop it in your files navigator (left panel in xcode).

Comment: Dragging into the navigator helped. Thank you so much.